# Is it correct to say 'warmer weather rots the fruit'?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, transitivity

Although commonly used as an intransitive verb, I understand 'rot' is also a transitive verb. So is it correct to say

> "Warmer weather rots the fruit."

Comment: It is correct grammatically. Whether it is correct **factually** is outside my competence. Which meaning of "correct" did you have in mind?

Comment: rots fruit [general] or rots the fruit [already menitoned?]. Big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noted, *rot* indeed can be used transitively to refer to an action taken by a subject, but it is a relatively rare usage compared to the verb being used intransitively to describe the process of decaying in something.

Here are some examples of *rot* being used as a transitive verb:

> Eating too much candy can rot your teeth. (from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rot))
>
> All that candy will rot your teeth. (from [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/rot_1))
>
> caries sets in at a weak point and spreads to rot the whole tooth (from [OOD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rot))

Funny so many oral hygiene references, isn't it? As you have correctly guessed, your sentence is grammatical, and you can perfectly say it. As for whether it is a factual statement, I am inclined to say yes too.